# c++ program, mutli-thread slower than single thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

my code is following. count the num of odd in the array. program do this in multi-thread way and single thread. it seem strangy that multi-thread way is slower. program is compile with option -O2, and run in ubuntu 20.0

(question need more detail description, but i dont know what else i can say, so i put some non-sense sentence here.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <chrono>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

const int buffer_size = 32 * 1024 * 1024;       // size of buffer
const int num_thds = 4;                         // number of threads

int* buffer = NULL;
int result[num_thds];                           // collect result from each thread
int chunk_size = buffer_size / num_thds + 1;    // size of chunk

void* foo(void *id)
{
    int tid = *((int*)id);
    int start = tid * chunk_size;
    int end = min((tid + 1) * chunk_size, buffer_size);

    result[tid] = 0;
    for (int i=start; i<end; i++) {
        if (buffer[i] % 2 != 0)
            ++result[tid];
    }

    return nullptr;
}

int multi_thread(int num_thds)
{
    pthread_t *thds = NULL;
    int *thd_ids;
    int count;

    count = 0;
    thds = new pthread_t[num_thds];
    thd_ids = new int[num_thds];

    auto start_time = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i=0; i<num_thds; i++) {
        thd_ids[i] = i;
        pthread_create(&thds[i], NULL, foo, &thd_ids[i]);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<num_thds; i++) {
        pthread_join(thds[i], NULL);
    }
    auto end_time = high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << "Time elapsed (Multi thread): "
         << duration_cast<microseconds>(end_time - start_time).count()
         << " us" << endl;

    for (int i=0; i<num_thds; i++)
        count += result[i];

    delete [] thds;
    delete [] thd_ids;

    return count;
}

int single()
{
    int count = 0;
    auto start_time = high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (int i=0; i<buffer_size; i++) {
        if (buffer[i] % 2 != 0)
            count++;
    }

    auto end_time = high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << "Time elapsed (Single): "
         << duration_cast<microseconds>(end_time - start_time).count()
         << " us" << endl;

    return count++;
}

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    buffer = new int[buffer_size];

    for (int i=0; i<buffer_size; i++) {
        buffer[i] = rand();
    }

    // single
    int count1 = single();

    // multi thread
    int count2 = multi_thread(num_thds);

    cout << "Count (Single): " << count1 << endl;
    cout << "Count (Multi Thread): " << count2 << endl;

    delete [] buffer;
    buffer = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

and the program output is

```
Time elapsed (Single): 58461 us
Time elapsed (Multi thread): 119355 us
Count (Single): 16775398
Count (Multi Thread): 16775398
```

Comment: your single threaded one takes 58 milliseconds, thats too little to justify multithreading. Spawning threads is overhead.

Comment: Traversing an array sequentially is much more cache-friendly than the jumping about you get when multithreading. Randomizing the accesses in `single` makes it much slower than the multithreaded version.

Comment: i agree that randomizing accesses make multi-thread method slower, and if i want to optimize this program, what else can i do?

Comment: @molbdnilo: With multi-threading and modern CPU's, you typically get multiple cores assigned, which have their own L1 caches. The main memory bandwidth will likely exceed the capability of a single core, so threading could make sense. I agree with largest_prime; thread creation looks like the culprit.